# How to insert a non-stretching but line-breaking thin space?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

How do I insert a small space that looks like the space I get with `\,` but allows a line break like a normal space does? I.e., I'm looking for a non-stretching, non-non-breaking space whose width is identical to `\,`.

I have already tried `some\,\allowbreak{}text` but, in case of a line break, this keeps the `\,` space at the end of the line which is not what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `biblatex` package provides the `\addthinspace` macro which *"[a]dds a* breakable *thin space"* (manual, section 4.7.4). Here's a variant that omits the `biblatex`-specific stuff. (Note that `\,` in text mode uses `\thinspace` which is defined as `\kern 0.16667em`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\addthinspace}{\hskip0.16667em\relax}

\textwidth=52pt

\begin{document}

\noindent xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx\addthinspace aaa\addthinspace aaa

\bigskip

\noindent xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx\,aaa\,aaa

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a simple way to express this in a generic way so that one could write something like `\breakingspace{\,}` to insert the space?

Comment: @Bloops Locally redefining `\,` is beyond my abilities.

Answer (score 9):

The `\breakingspace` macro can be obtained quite easily:

```
\newcommand{\breakingspace}[1]{#1\hspace{0pt}}
```

Quoting from the TeXbook (p. 96):

> Line breaks can occur only in certain places within a horizontal list. Roughly speaking, they occur between words and after hyphens, but in actuality they are permitted in the following five cases:
>
> a) at glue, provided that this glue is immediately preceded by a non-discardable item, and that it is not part of a math formula (i.e., not
>   between math-on and math-off). A break “at glue” occurs at the left edge
>   of the glue space.
>
> b) at a kern, provided that this kern is immediately followed by glue, and that it is not part of a math formula.
>
> c) at a math-off that is immediately followed by glue.
>
> d) at a penalty (which might have been inserted automatically in a formula).
>
> e) at a discretionary break.

Another way might be

```
\newcommand{\breakingspace}[1]{{\let\kern\hskip#1}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\breakingspace}[1]{#1\hspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\parbox{\widthof{a\,a}}{
a\breakingspace{\,}a\breakingspace{\,}%
a\breakingspace{\,}a\breakingspace{\,}%
a\breakingspace{\,}a\breakingspace{\,}%
a}}

\renewcommand{\breakingspace}[1]{{\let\kern\hskip#1}}

\fbox{\parbox{\widthof{a\,a}}{
a\breakingspace{\,}a\breakingspace{\,}%
a\breakingspace{\,}a\breakingspace{\,}%
a\breakingspace{\,}a\breakingspace{\,}%
a}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With both definitions, `\breakingspace` will not do anything in math mode other than adding glue or kerns; with the other possibility

```
\newcommand{\badbreakingspace}[1]{\penalty 0 #1}
```

one would add a break point also in math mode.

Answer (score 7):

Just to mention that the simple `\allowbreak\,` seems to respond to the OP's demands. In this answer, I first tried with `\allowbreak\,\allowbreak` but this is a bit silly so I then turned to `\allowbreak\,`. As the OP said `\,\allowbreak` is a no-go. In passing, a funny effect is noticed when the text in the testing `\parbox` is not ended by a `\\` or  a `\par`.

---

In my testing `\allowbreak\,\allowbreak` works (in text mode, did not try math mode). To illustrate it and check that no `thin space` is present at the end of the line I replace in the following code the `\,` by a `\bigspace` of `2em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\ttfamily 

\newcommand\bigspace{\kern 2em}

\newlength\awidth
\settowidth{\awidth}{A\bigspace A\bigspace A}

\newcommand\breakingspace{\allowbreak\bigspace\allowbreak}

\fboxsep=0pt

\fbox{\parbox{\awidth}{
A\rule{2em}{1pt}A\rule{2em}{1pt}A\\
A\breakingspace
B\breakingspace
C\breakingspace
D\breakingspace
E\breakingspace
F\breakingspace
G\breakingspace
H\breakingspace
I\breakingspace
J\breakingspace
K\breakingspace
L\\
A\breakingspace
B\breakingspace
C\breakingspace
D\breakingspace
E\breakingspace
F\breakingspace
G\breakingspace
H\breakingspace
I\breakingspace
J\breakingspace
K\breakingspace
L\breakingspace
}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the code]

Hope somebody will explain the behavior at the end of the text when it is ended by `\breakingspace`. . .

---

Actually, `\allowbreak\,` works about the same as `\allowbreak\,\allowbreak`. As shown by this variant:

```
\renewcommand\breakingspace{\allowbreak\bigspace}

\fbox{\parbox{\awidth}{
A\rule{2em}{1pt}A\rule{2em}{1pt}A\\
A\breakingspace
B\breakingspace
C\breakingspace
D\breakingspace
E\breakingspace
F\breakingspace
G\breakingspace
H\breakingspace
I\breakingspace
J\breakingspace
K\breakingspace
L\breakingspace
}}
\fbox{\parbox{\awidth}{
A\rule{2em}{1pt}A\rule{2em}{1pt}A\\
A\breakingspace
B\breakingspace
C\breakingspace
D\breakingspace
E\breakingspace
F\breakingspace
G\breakingspace
H\breakingspace
I\breakingspace
J\breakingspace
K\breakingspace
L\breakingspace
M\breakingspace
}}
```

[image: second image]

I deliberately left `\breakingspace` at the end, rather than `\par` to show a funny effect. It is also interesting how the behavior is slightly different for the two definitions of `\breakingspace`. Note though that in both cases nothing surprising happens if one ends the thing with a `\par` rather than a `\breakingspace`.

Comment: `\allowbreak\,` is exactly my third solution. At the end of a paragraph kerns are *not* discarded; only *one* trailing glue item is.

Comment: @egreg: sorry I overlooked that, but it is good news as it means it does the expected thing in math mode, correct? and about the behavior of TeX's paragraph builder when such a thing rather than \\ or `\par` ends it? (you say kerns are not discarded, but how does it end up influencing the /first/ line of the paragraph?)