# How to get autobreaking with sequential tables

Tags: tables, spacing, line-breaking

So it appears that `\hspace` is not breakable, but is if it is followed by `\allowbreak`. Alternatively you can use `\hskip1.0em` as that is breakable.

So, if my understanding is correct, then why do the  tables in red not show up on the left hand side?

[image]

### Question:

- How do I handle this situation where I have a bunch of tables in a row and want them to go next to each other (if they fit on the remainder of the current line), or go the next line.

### Notes:

- The `\hspace` macro seems to fix the case for the first set of table, but not for the second set.
- This is for an internal document, so not too concerned how good it looks. Well at least not yet. :-)

### References:

- [How to insert a non-stretching but line-breaking thin space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78914/how-to-insert-a-non-stretching-but-line-breaking-thin-space)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Space}{\hskip1.0em}%
%\newcommand*{\Space}{\hspace*{1.0em}\allowbreak}%  `\allowbreak`.
\newcommand*{\MyTabularA}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}%
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
        1 & 2 & A\\%
        3 & 4 & B\\%
        5 & 6 & C\\%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyTabularB}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}%
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & A\\%
        3 & 4 & B\\%
        5 & 6 & C\\%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}\noindent
\MyTabularA\Space%
\MyTabularA\Space%
\color{red}\MyTabularA\Space%
\color{blue}\MyTabularA\Space%
\MyTabularA\Space%


\bigskip\color{black}\noindent
\MyTabularB\Space%
\MyTabularB\Space%
\MyTabularB\Space%
\MyTabularB\Space%
\MyTabularB\Space%
\color{red}\MyTabularB\Space%
\color{blue}\MyTabularB\Space%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have been told my questions are hard. Well this should be easy, just hope it is not so easy that it is another of my embarrassing questions. :-)

Comment: The assumption on the first line of the question is false. Your commented code use `\hspace*` not `\hspace` the `*` form is explicitly to stop the space being discarded at a line break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\raggedright%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference whatsoever between `\hspace{1em}` and `\hskip1em` (so long as the latter is not followed by `plus` or `minus`: with the former you get the internal version

```
\@hspace{1em}
```

which finally expands to `\hskip 1em\relax`.

What's the problem in your document? A `tabular` environment is, to TeX, just like a big letter. It wants simply to typeset paragraphs following its rules. Indeed you get two messages:

```
Overfull \hbox (168.00093pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 24--30
[] [] [][]

Overfull \hbox (26.00035pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 32--40
[] [] [] [] [] [][]
```

that simply mean: "Dear Peter, I couldn't typeset your paragraphs without violating the current `\tolerance`, so I've left lines sticking out in the right margin."

Exactly the same happens if you define

```
\newcommand*{\Space}{\hspace{1.0em}}
```

because you're just telling TeX the same thing.

Justification is obtained easily by allowing stretchability to `\Space`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Space}{\hspace{1.0em plus 3em}}
\newcommand*{\MyTabularA}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
        1 & 2 & A\\
        3 & 4 & B\\
        5 & 6 & C\\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand*{\MyTabularB}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & A\\
        3 & 4 & B\\
        5 & 6 & C\\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\MyTabularA\Space
\MyTabularA\Space
\color{red}\MyTabularA\Space
\color{blue}\MyTabularA\Space
\MyTabularA

\bigskip

\color{black}\noindent
\MyTabularB\Space
\MyTabularB\Space
\MyTabularB\Space
\MyTabularB\Space
\MyTabularB\Space
\color{red}\MyTabularB\Space
\color{blue}\MyTabularB

\end{document}
```

(I've removed the useless things, as usual. `;-)`)

[image]

Of course, the final line in the second paragraph doesn't stretch the space, because of TeX's rules.

Comment: yes although the OP referenced a question specifically about non-stretching space which is why in my version I left the inter-table glue as non stretchy and added the stretch at the right via `\raggedright` (extensively documented as usual:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The reference to a non-stretching space is not in the main question, where it's unclear what the aim is regarding justification. Let's wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- right.  oops!  (that suggestion deleted.  yours is correct though.)